# Search for a string in a collection of dlls

Tags: dll, resource-files

We have a number of dlls in a single directory. Most, but not all, are C++ resource dlls only. These dlls can be opened in Visual Studio for a "visual" inspection (you can see the "String Table").

Here's the scenario, we are looking for a particular string but we don't which DLL contains the string. Is there a tool that we can use that will perform a string search on DLLs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) command to search strings in several files.

Comment: It's not that smart: it will just match what looks like strings in the binary soup of the files. That may be enough, though.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me but my Command prompt usually crashes when I use findstr on a bunch of dlls.

Answer (score 2):

I've just successfully used **.NET Reflector 6** to find a string (using `Ctrl+S`) in the list of loaded DLLs.

Slightly off for the original question (concerning C++) but I've stumbled upon this question by the title and this is my answer.